# Issue with EVP_aes_128_ctr when moving from fc17 to fc18

Tags: linux, openssl, pyinstaller

In fc17 the openssl version is 1.0.0k while in fc18 the openssl version is 1.0.1e

In the following [link](http://upstream-tracker.org/compat_reports/openssl/1.0.0k_to_1.0.1/abi_compat_report.html) we can see that this symbol was added to 1.0.1 but I can not understand how to fix these errors

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
/lib/libssh2.so.1: symbol EVP_aes_128_ctr, version libcrypto.so.10 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference
```

and

```
git-remote-https: /tmp/_MEIo4w334/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by /lib/libssh2.so.1)
git-remote-https: relocation error: /lib/libssh2.so.1: symbol EVP_aes_128_ctr, version libcrypto.so.10 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference
```

Any idea what's wrong or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with pyinstaller. `yum` and `git` commands work perfectly fine when run from cli. These commands are called from a binary created by pyinstaller from a python script. When I use the script directly it works fine hence the problem is pyinstaller.

Edit:

In fact the problem wasn't even with pyinstaller, it was the packaging. I created the binary using pyinstaller on fc17 and used the binary on fc18, this was the root cause to the problem above. If I build the binary on fc18, I can run it with no problem on fc18.